Euler bricks with same smallest side.
An Euler brick is a triple of positive integers $(a, b, c)$ with $a\leq b\leq c$ such that $a^2+b^2, a^2+c^2, b^2+c^2$ are all squares. We call $a, b, c$ the side lengths of said Euler brick.
As a follow-up to this question, I am wondering about the existence of distinct Euler bricks with the same smallest side length. In other words, do there exist Euler bricks $(a, b, c)$ and $(a, b', c')$ where $b\neq b'$ and $c\neq c'$? How many distinct Euler bricks can exist with a fixed smallest side?

Take any 2 Euler bricks $(a, b, c)$ and $(A, B, C)$, then $(aA, bA, cA)$ and $(aA, aB, aC)$ are Euler bricks with the same smallest length. $\quad$ We can extend this approach to $n$ Euler bricks, and create $n$ Euler bricks with the same smallest length.

If you insist on primitive Euler bricks (that is, $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, there are (at least) two with smallest side $1008$. See https://oeis.org/A031175 – then from https://oeis.org/A031173/a031173.txt we can see they are $(1155, 1100, 1008)$ and $(12075, 1100, 1008)$.

There are also two at $2964$.
